# how to protect against ActionNotSupportedException after adding new method to WCF callback

Tags: wcf

I have Wcf Server with callback information:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IUpdateServerServiceCallback))]
public interface IUpdateServerService 
{
...
}
```

When user connects to the server I remember callback like so:

```
u.UpdateServerServiceCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IUpdateServerServiceCallback>();
```

I have added new method to `IUpdateServerServiceCallback` 
When I call this method on new clients it is working fine, but when I call this method on old clients it throws `ActionNotSupportedException` and since than I can not call any method on callback (Exception: `Cannot access a disposed object, object name: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel`)

How can I check if client supports this new method?  Basically if client is old I need to call `Method1`, if it is new `Method2`.